# Renaming a module in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, directory-structure

I work on spring boot application. When I click on module->Refactor/Rename I get two options:

[image]

I know what renaming directory is, but what about renaming module?
What does this change do?

Comment: In gradle, at least, your project is split into modules. If you only have one module, then the module name is the same as your project name (usually).

Comment: @Campbell but what about renaming each separate module?

Comment: I get "cannot rename root module". It looks impossible?

Answer (score 3):

A module is a part of a project that you can compile, run, test and debug independently. It is a way to reduce complexity of large projects while maintaining a common (project) configuration. They are reusable: if necessary, a module can be included in more than one project.

If you change your project name to something completely different, you might want to rename your modules as well. It just renames the module.

Comment: Module names are determined by maven artifact ids.

Comment: but when I change module name nothing happened

Comment: i'm not quite sure what you mean

Comment: artifact ids are not changed after I change module name. I cannot see the impact of changing module name..?

Comment: @IvanAracki In recent versions the artifact id changes as well. As I only want to change the visual name I now have to undo the changes in the pom.xml as there doesn't seem to be an option to control that. Looks like different users have different requirements :)